# How to get string / line between 2 strings using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am bit new for Regex class in C#. I have use case like I have some file where we have data in following format :--

```
----string1
abc
cde
--string1
efg
hjk
-string1
xyz
string1
```

Now when I am using like `string1(.+?)string1` as pattern I am getting following 2 result :--
`abc, cde` and `xyz`.
But I want `abc, cde`, `efg, hjk` and `xyz`. 
Can you suggest how can I do it ?

There is one more issue - how to handle variable numbers of "-" as right now I am ignoring it (in my above example) but I have to handle it later on.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What exactly is your input? It would help if you are formatting your question a bit to make clear what's one input example and the expected result.

Comment: Try using look behind and look ahead for the "string1" parts so that your matches will not eat them when it moves on to the next.  `(?<=string1)(.+?)(?=string1)`http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: HI Mighty, I am using Regex class of C# to parse the string and my input is a string where "string1" you can consider as boundaries. Now I would like to get the result between these boundaries.

Comment: Just split with `string1` (or `Regex.Split(s, "(?m)^-+string1\r?$")`) and then split each item in the resulting list/array with linebreaks. Or use a scary [regex like this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e-%2bstring%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%5b%5cr%5cn%5d%2b%28%3f!%5e-%2bstring%5cd%2b%29%28.*%29%29*&i=----string1%0d%0aabc%0d%0acde%0d%0a--string1%0d%0aefg%0d%0ahjk%0d%0a-string1%0d%0axyz%0d%0astring1&o=m).

Answer (score -1):

The closing `string1` should be a positive lookbehind to make it match in the following iteration:

```
string1(.+?)(?=string1)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=string1%28.%2b%3f%29%28%3f%3dstring1%29&i=----string1%0d%0aabc%0d%0acde%0d%0a--string1%0d%0aefg%0d%0ahjk%0d%0a-string1%0d%0axyz%0d%0astring1&o=s).

As of the variable number of dashes, just prepend your `string1` with `-*`:

```
-*string1(.+?)(?=-*string1)
```

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-*string1%28.%2b%3f%29%28%3f%3d-*string1%29&i=----string1%0d%0aabc%0d%0acde%0d%0a--string1%0d%0aefg%0d%0ahjk%0d%0a-string1%0d%0axyz%0d%0astring1&o=s)

Comment: Hi Dmitry, "-" is a character here not the positive or negative sign. I don't why my question has been voted down ?

Comment: @user1677408: Hi! Yes, I also interpreted this just as a character without any mathematical meaning. I'm not sure why your question has been downvoted.